# Mapping values of one pandas column to another when column lengths are not the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the following data

```
data1 = [['date1', 10], ['date2', 15], ['date3', 14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['date', 'value'])

data2 = [['date1', 1], ['date2', 2], ['date3', 3], ['date1', 4], ['date2', 5], ['date3', 6]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['date', 'value'])
```

[image: example 1]

Basically I want it to look like this

```
data3 = [['date1', 1, 10], ['date2', 2, 15], ['date3', 3, 14], ['date1', 4, 10], ['date2', 5, 15], ['date3', 6, 14]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['date', 'value', 'other value'])
df3
```

[image]

Where the values from the first dataframe are mapped to specific row values. Is this possible in Pandas? I haven't been able to find out how to do this and I am starting to believe this is not a possibility.

Comment: Did you try merge? `df2.merge(df1,on='date',how='left',suffixes=('','_other'))`

Comment: @anky perfect this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `assign()` method and `set_index()` method:

```
df3=df2.set_index('date').assign(other_value=df1.set_index('date'))
```

**OR**

As suggested by @anky in comment use `merge()` method as it is easier to write:

```
df3=df2.merge(df1,on='date',how='left')
```

**Performace:**

[image]